# Best practices to secure rest api with gateway and spring security OAuth

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I would like to ask what are the best practices to secure application with

[following architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTokw.png)

Currently it is works like this:

1. all requests pass spring gateway
2. user fetch JWT token from aut server
3. user fetch /endpoint from service B. Service B use spring security (oauth resource server) and automatically validate token on auth server. Then check permissions via annotation e.g. hasRole('MANAGER')
4. service B needs internally fetch data from service C, so it makes request to it with http client (add current JWT into header)
5. On service C spring security validate token (again) and return response to service B.

Is this correct approach that each service validate token? 
Should I do any security on gateway? If yes, how? 
Is possible to validate JWT on gateway only? So each service doesn't have to validate it again?
Should JWT contains also permissions or only roles and fetch permissions from auth server? Fetching of permissions should do each microservice or gateway and create some internal token? 
Thank you

Comment: @martinspielmann thank you for pointing this post. Yes it answers many of my questions. I think I was already looking on it, but because of headline I was thinking it is about some issue of "Decoding Jwt" and didn't go deeper into it. Thanks again.

Comment: Cool, glad i could help, thanks  for your feedback!